# How to add a hover to swap images contained within a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to change the image I have inside a flex element, but at this point, I'm running out of ideas of what I could do, or if it's even possible. Also, I want to keep the colour of the background behind the image, if it makes any difference.

This is also my first time using flexbox. I started learning to code three days ago. So I'm sorry if it's a dumb question.

HTML

```
    <main>
        <section class="digital">
            <img src="images/digital.png" alt="digital">
        </section>
        <section class="graphic">
            <img src="images/graphic.png" alt="graphic">
        </section>
        <section class="fashion">
            <img src="images/fashion.png" alt="fashion">
        </section>
        <section class="social">
            <img src="images/social.png" alt="social">
        </section>
    </main>
```

CSS

```
main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.digital{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background: #9EF7CD;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.graphic{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background: #FF8CAE;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.fashion{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background: #F4B550;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.social{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background: #9BC1FF;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
'''
```

Comment: there are two good ways of achieving image switch that i can think of.
1. placing images on top of each other, on img:hover {display: none} for the top picture.
2. use a picture as a background of a div, within that div have the other image displayed on top of the other, on hover you can set display to none on the image or you can set opacity: 0.

Comment: How do you want to swap, swap `digital` to `graphic` and vise versa ?

Comment: Hi @Stanley, I will give it a try again. I tried that before, but I was using "position: absolute" to have them on top of each other, which made both images get out of the box. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @DickensAS. Sorry I should have been more clear. Actually, the image I want to use as image2 is not in the code. I was trying to use "background-image: url();" to place them straight in the CSS, no luck with that. Thank you!

Comment: background-url works for for me, I just tested, do you want the code ?

Comment: Hi @DickensAS, sure that would be great. Using Stanley's tip above, I was able to make it work by adding divs, the second image, and class to each div to the HTML, but can't figure it out how to place them on top of each other. 

`.digital{
 flex: 1 1 auto;
 background: #9EF7CD;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.digital1:hover{
 display: none;
}
.digital2{

}`

Thank you very much!

Comment: I gave the answer using `background-image` and `:hover`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I arrived at a solution! Not sure if it's the most elegant, but it's working the way I intended.

Thank you, everyone, who helped!

```
    <main>
        <section class="digital">
            <div class="digital1"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="graphic">
            <div class="graphic1"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="fashion">
            <div class="fashion1"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="social">
            <div class="social1"></div>
        </section>
    </main>
```

CSS

```
main{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 650px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.digital{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    background: #9EF7CD;
    height: 650px;
    width: 250px;
}
.digital1{
    height: 650px;
    width: 250px;
    background-image: url(../images/digital-1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.digital1:hover{
    background-image: url(../images/digital-2.png);
}
.graphic{
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    display: inline-flex;
    background: #FF8CAE;
    height: 650px;
    width: 250px;
}
.graphic1{
    height: 650px;
    width: 250px;
    background-image: url(../images/graph-1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.graphic1:hover{
    background-image: url(../images/graph-2.png);
}
.fashion{
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    display: inline-flex;
    background: #F4B550;
    height: 650px;
    width: 250px;
}
.fashion1{
    height: 650px;
    width: 250px;
    background-image: url(../images/fashion-1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.fashion1:hover{
    background-image: url(../images/fashion-2.png);
}
.social{
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    display: inline-flex;
    background: #9BC1FF;
    height: 650px;
    width: 250px;
}
.social1{
    height: 650px;
    width: 250px;
    background-image: url(../images/social-1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.social1:hover{
    background-image: url(../images/social-2.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the image to CSS `background-image` and write `:hover` for the main tag itself

```css
main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.digital{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background: #9EF7CD;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
 background-image: url('images/digital.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.digital:hover{
    background-image: url('images/graphic.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.graphic{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background: #FF8CAE;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
 background-image: url('images/graphic.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.graphic:hover{
    background-image: url('images/digital.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.fashion{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background: #F4B550;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
 background-image: url('images/fashion.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.fashion:hover{
    background-image: url('images/social.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.social{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background: #9BC1FF;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
 background-image: url('images/social.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.social:hover{
    background-image: url('images/fashion.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<main>
 <section class="digital"></section>
 <section class="graphic"></section>
 <section class="fashion"></section>
 <section class="social"></section>
</main>
```

You can remove the second tag
To change the size and position of the image
You can use `background-position` and `background-size` CSS

Comment: Thank you Dickens, better cleaner version! If you want, check it on codepen https://codepen.io/diegomoura/project/editor/XYQKRp